# How to call a java servlet using ajax from controller

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I create a bar column chart.. in my controller I want to call a servlet.. In my function i take a variable which holds the instacne of store using getStore('StoreName').. now how can I call the ajax??? please anyone help me.. here is my controller...

```
Ext.define('Gamma.controller.ControlFile', {    
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller', 
//define the stores
stores : ['BarColumn','RadarView','VoiceCallStore','SMSCallStore','MMSCallStore','GPRSUsageStore'],
//define the models 
models : ['BarCol','radar','VoiceCallModel','SMSCallModel','MMSCallModel','GPRSUsageModel'],
//define the views
views : ['BarColumnChart','LineChart','RadarChart','VoicePie','SMSPie','MMSPie','GPRSPie'],

initializedEvents: false,
init: function() {
    this.control({
        '#barColumnChart': {
            afterlayout: this.afterChartLayout
        }
    });
},
afterChartLayout: function(){
    var me=this;
    if(this.initializedEvents==true) return;
    this.initializedEvents=true;
    Ext.getCmp('barColumnChart').series.items[0].on('itemmousedown',function(obj){
        var barData=obj.storeItem.data['source']+ ' &' + obj.storeItem.data['count'];
            me.dataBaseCall(barData);
    });
},
dataBaseCall: function(barData){
    var bar=getStore('BarColumn');

    //here I want to call the ajax

}

});
```

here is the code of my store for bar column chart..

```
Ext.define('Gamma.store.BarColumn', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'Gamma.model.BarCol',
autoLoad: true,
pageSize: 100,

  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '../TopCount', //this my servlet name
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'topList',
        totalProperty: 'totalCount',
        successProperty: 'success'
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code in the controller block

dataBaseCall: function(barData){
    var bar=getStore('BarColumn');

```
 var store = Ext.create('Gamma.store.BarColumn');

 // to create storeid use below code
  var store = Ext.create('Gamma.store.BarColumn', {storeId: 'BarColumnID'});
```

}

Comment: okk thanks for ur response Hariharan.. but where and how I should call the ajax method to call servlet???

Comment: @Subhajyoti It will call automatically because you made the config as  autoLoad:true in store. If you specify autoLoad:false then u need to manually invoke load method to call ajax request. All servlet request will be taken care by Proxy in store( where you specify the URL).  More over your are defining store with define class, when u call create for that define, at that point only request will be send to servlet.